# How to cast string to OracleClob object in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

hi i have an field has OracleClob type.I want to cast this as my string data.How can i do it in c# ?

```
 [MapField("MSG_BODY")]
 public Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleClob MsgBody { get; set; }
```

i want to set MsgBody : "This is a sample";

I have to define an oracleclob object and fill it as string text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleClobClass.htm) you need to write it with a buffered array, so something like this:

```
char[] writeBuffer = "This is a sample".ToCharArray();
this.MsgBody.Write(writerBuffer, 0, writeBuffer.Length);
this.MsgBody.Close();
this.MsgBody.Dispose();
```

and bear in mind I'm assuming you've created the `OracleClob` with an open `OracleConnection`.

Comment: i use bltoolkit for oracle connection with connectionstr.I have no oracleconnection obj do i have to create it only for using this?

Comment: @Mennan: according to the documentation (if you look at the code example) you have to create an `OracleClob` with a connection. If this is being done by the framework you're leveraging, fine, I'm just letting you know that an `OracleClob` isn't a plain old class - it's special and requires some interesting initialization and interaction.

Comment: i understand the problem thx for your helping i research documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I've never touched Oracle, but according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleClobClass.htm) you can handle it like a byte stream.

Add a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) and you should be able to do

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(MsgBody, Encoding.UTF8); // Assuming you want UTF-8
sw.Write("This is a sample");
sw.Flush();
```

Comment: Where did you get the error from? Writing? Flushing? Saving? You may also need to always create a new OracleClob to write to, then assign it to the MsgBody.

Comment: error on writing.I use bltoolkit for connect to oracle.i think i have to create new connection only for creating new clob obj